# How many words can be formed, given $4$ letters, and in each word there must be at least two letters are the same?

Tags: combinatorics

How many words can be formed, given $4(a,b,c,d)$ letters, and in each word from $4$ letters there must be at least two letters are the same? The position of the letter doesn't matter. The answer is $232,$ I don't know how to "attack" it.

Comment: How long are the words?

Comment: 4 letters, forgot the add this.

Comment: What do you mean "position doesn't matter"? Is "abbc" and "abcb" equal?

Comment: There are $4^4$ possible words in total. There are $4!=24$ words with no repeats. Hence $256-24=232$ with at least one repeat.

Comment: @almagest, give this as answer so I can mark it as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $4^4=256$ possible words in total. There are $4!=24$ words with no repeats. Hence $256−24=232$ with at least one repeat.